# Featured image not working

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-featured-image

I want to use a featured image in my post pages,
The problem is, i don't see this.
How can i do that?

I thought I had to write this code in functions.php and that this was resolved
add_theme_support('post_thumbnails');

But unfortunately.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This function is useful to get the featured image into the post pages. you can add this into your loop also pass the $post_id, $size, $attr into that function.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```